# Emacs - color of directories in dired

Tags: emacs, dired, font-lock, emacs-faces

I have search the web.  I have tried color-theme (perhaps I need to create my own, but really I have my emacs set up the way I want it except for this ONE thing, and I could not find a color theme that was acceptable to me).

I just want to change the color of the directories in dired-mode.  I have several custom colors changed in my .emacs, like:

```
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "yellow" )
```

But I just don't know what face to change for the directories in dired mode.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: <http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you move point to the place that's displaying the color you want to change and run `M-x describe-face`, it will tell you the face for the text at point and that face's properties.

For me, it's `dired-directory`, not font-lock-comment-face.

Comment: I did M-x describe-face, and it asked me for a face name!

Comment: The default face (if you just hit enter) will be the current face.

Comment: describe-face on the dired for me makes "Describe face:" appear in the mini buffer, and if I hit return, nothing happens.

Comment: What version of emacs are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I managed to list the faces by doing M-x list-faces-display, and then I found the faces that had the dark blue that I didn't want, and, although none of the face descriptions said anything remotely like "Directory Name in dired", I just changed all of the faces that had unreadable colors, and my problems were solved!

Answer (score 1):

```
(set-face-foreground 'dired-directory "yellow" )
```

Comment: Response was:  "Invalid face: dired-directory"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run:

<kbd>M-x customize-face dired-directory</kbd>

You'll then be presented with a menu of attributes you can customize.  Select `Save for future sessions` and your `.emacs` will automatically be updated to make the change permanent.

Comment: I got no match on dired-directory

Comment: Did you autoload or `load-library` dired?  The variables for that mode (including faces) are lazily initialized.

Answer (score 1):

diredful (dired colorful) worked for me.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Diredful

https://github.com/emacsmirror/diredful

To match directories:

1. Pattern: d.*
2. Select regexp on whole line (so it matches the permissions containing the 'd')
3. Check apply to Dirctories
4. Style the colors.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an older version of emacs (i tested emacs 21) try "list-text-properties-at" instead of "describe-face".  for me, it shows the directory face as "font-lock-function-name-face".